# Populating View fields from Controller in Grails

Tags: grails, view, controllers

I am trying to load a value into a field on a view from the action on a controller.  How do I reference the specific field I want to load?  In .NET it would be something like: in the button click event, this.txtName.Text = "John".  I don't understand how to do that from a controller and specifically how to reference the view field.  I have tried using the params object but it is coming null.  I know I am getting to the action based on println statements that I have used.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

from the view:

```
<td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: planetInstance, field: 'name', 'errors')}">
  <g:textField name="name" value="${planetInstance?.name}"/>
</td>
<td class="load">
  <g:actionSubmit value="Load" action="nameLoad"/>
</td>
```

from the controller:

```
def nameLoad = {
    // I want to reference and load the "name" textField from the view
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you use `grails generate-all` to generate some CRUD pages for one of your domain classes. Have a look at the code that's generated to see how this should be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell from your code, but you may have forgotten to map the variable `name` in your controller action `nameLoad`:

```
class YourController{    
    def nameLoad = {
        def name = Planet.get(params.id).name //This can be whatever you need it to be to get the correct value assigned to the "name" variable.  Here I assume you have a domain class called "Planet" which may or may not be the case.
        return [name:name] //This is where you map key/value pairs.  The name of the key is what you will type to access the value in your view.  The value is the name of the variable you are dealing with, in this case "name".
    }
}
```

With the way the code above is set up Grails will assume there is a view called `nameLoad` in the folder `YourController`.  So the URL will be something like:

`http://localhost:8080/yourapp/yourcontroller/nameload`

In that view you will access `name` like this:

`${name}`

Which could be used in any number of tags, like the `<g:select>` tag for instance:

```
<g:select from="${name}" />
```

Comment: When I try the code you mention above, I get an error on the def name... line that says: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
 at grailstagstest.PlanetController$_closure9.doCall(PlanetController.groovy:103)

Comment: I finally got it to work using the following code in the nameLoad action on the controller:

def planetInstance = new Planet()
planetInstance.properties = params
planetInstance.name = "Jupiter"
render(view: "create", model: [planetInstance: planetInstance])

Comment: I didn't create anything in the code I gave you because the name of your action was `nameLoad` not `create`, but the concept is the same. As I noted in the first comment in the code I posted, you have to fill the variable in question using whatever code is appropriate (in your case I guess creating a new planet is appropriate) then mapping that variable. Using `render` as you did allows you to use a view that is not named the same as your controller action, the way I showed you assumed a view with the same name as your controller action existed (which I noted in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the value of the text field with `params.name`.  If that's not working, you may have a problem with your view.  Are the `g:textField` and `g:actionSubmit` tags enclosed in a `form` or `g:form`?

Comment: Yes, I have the g:textField and g:actionSubmit tags inside of a g:form tag.